# Hiding sensitive ruby shell commands

Tags: ruby, shell, fastlane

I'm using fastlane and sh command to decrypt some credentials but seems ruby prints the output in logs. How do I hide the sensitive information from logs?

```
cmd_decrypt = "openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k \"#{ENV["MATCH_PASSWORD"]}\" -in #{enc_file} -out #{dec_file[0]}"

sh(cmd_decrypt)
```

output:

```
[09:38:15]: --------------------------------------------------------------------
[09:38:15]: Step: openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k "PASSWORD_SHOWN!" -in /var/folders/7g/yy/T/d20190925-1304-1qv6cj1/vault/zz-out /var/folders/7g/yy/T/d20190925-1304-1qv6cj1/vault/xx
[09:38:15]: --------------------------------------------------------------------
[09:38:15]: $ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k "PASSWORD_SHOWN!" -in /var/folders/7g/yy/T/d20190925-1304-1qv6cj1/vault/zz -out /var/folders/7g/yy/T/d20190925-1304-1qv6cj1/vault/xx
```

Comment: What is producing the log files? And where does the `sh` method come from?

Comment: the logs are shown in build logs in the CI pipeline[TravisCI/CircleCI/etc]. I have a .yaml build file for CI which calls > bash script>which calls fastlane commands

Comment: My guess is CI is logging STDOUT and you need to stop fastlane (whatever that is) outputing to STDOUT for the those specific commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `sh` extra parameters. In this case, you would call it like this:

```
sh(cmd_decrypt, log: false)
```

The documentation for `sh` is here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sh/

You get can get the docs for other built-in actions here:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/

And the docs for other plugin's actions here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins/

Comment: I recommend browsing through the docs to find other potentially useful commands that you can use. Sometimes, you'll find that you're doing something the hard way when there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an environment variable, why not just run with that?

```
cmd_decrypt = "openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k \"$MATCH_PASSWORD\" -in #{enc_file} -out #{dec_file[0]}"

sh(cmd_decrypt)
```

From there shell interpolation should take over and make it work. One thing to note is your `-in` parameter doesn't have shell escaping, which it usually must have, done using [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape).

You *really* should be specifying these as separate arguments, though, whenever possible to avoid injection issues. The problem is you lose shell interpolation at that point.

The good news is you can always write a wrapper script to provide safety and ease of use, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# descrypt.sh

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k "$MATCH_PASSWORD" -in $1 -out $2
```

So then you can call it like this:

```
sh('descrypt.sh', enc_file, dec_file[0])
```

Now it logs something a lot quieter as well as a bonus. You can pick which arguments to pass through, or even throw them all through with `$*`.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson The second form should, as those are just regular Ruby variables that get passed through as arguments.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson Always good to have two sets of eyes on the documentation.